# как сделать чтобы парсер работал постоянно?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, веб-скрейпинг

Вот, например, на сайте новое обьявление, и я хочу, чтобы он взял сразу эту информацию. Если что, все в таблице.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://krisha.kz/arenda/kvartiry/almaty/"

response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
check = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'a-card__header')

results = []
for result in check:
    link = result.find('a', href=True)
    tex = result.text.strip()
    if link:
        lin = "https://krisha.kz" + link['href']
    results.append([tex, lin])

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Tex', 'Lin'])
df.to_excel('results.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: обернуть код в бесконечный цикл, с некоторой паузой вконце каждой итерации

Comment: И не впихивать в заголовок весь вопрос. Заголовок нужен для описания сути вашей проблемы, а не пространных объяснений.

Comment: а можно еще вопрос что такое тело программы? это весь код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только в режиме цикла, постоянно запрашивая код сайта и проверяя его. Только так.

```
repeat = True
while repeat:
    #ТЕЛО ПРОГРАММЫ
    time.sleep(600)
```

Comment: Спасибо, Глеб!)

Comment: Спасибо но я просто первый раз на сайте и только неделю назад начал  изучать программирование

Comment: Это нормально, я вообще не программист, но здесь народ адекватный - помогут, не пошлют. Еще и чего нового узнаешь

Comment: а можно еще вопрос что такое тело программы? это весь код?

Comment: Это твой код, да. И программа будет проверять его в установленные тобой сроки. Под твоим непосредственно вопросом другой человек написал про то ж, я пометил +1

Comment: все спасибо большое

Comment: можешь пожалуйста написать как должен выглядеть мой код просто у меня не получается может у меня потому что я код в excel ?

Comment: Нет, не могу. Немного подумай, скопируй свой код, посмотри, что нужно изменить, и вставь его вместо слов #ТЕЛО ПРОГРАММЫ